# how to retrieve variable instead of echo

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've just started to learn Ajax and want to know how to get a PHP variable instead of `echo` i [followed this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woNQ2MA_0XU&index=10&list=PL00952AC35D0A4701).

ajax_php_code.php

```
echo 'Your name is '.$_POST['firstname'].''$_POST['lastname].'';
```

html/ajax

```
function ajax_post(){
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest ();
var url = "ajax_php_code.php";
var fn = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
var ln = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;
hr.open("POST", url, true);

hr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}

hr.send(vars);
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "processing...";

}

<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Namn"  />
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Efternamn"  />
<input type="submit" value="Skicka data" id="knapp" />
<div id="status">
```

This is working fine but I would like to have a variable sent instead of echo is it possible?

Comment: You can use JSON format, to echo JSON string in your PHP script, then you can decode this string in your Javascript to manipulate variables.

Comment: @a-p Why did you add the Youtube link? Did the OP confirm that he was indeed following that tutorial?

Comment: Most importantly, why was the edit approved?

Comment: I rolled the YouTube video edit back.

Comment: Ok, we may move this to chat or meta but why should the video be there if the OP never put it there and never mentioned that he was following that video?

Comment: I was following the youtube video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to have your PHP send back JSON, and then parse that JSON client-side.

For instance, in the PHP:

```
$data = array(
    firstname => $_POST['firstname'],
    lastname =>  $_POST['lastname']
);
header("Content-Type", "application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then client-side, in your ajax success function:

```
var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
// Now you can use data.firstname and data.lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure it is possible:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $your_variable='value';
    echo json_encode($your_variable);
?>
```

Comment: the variable will be available to respose

Answer (score 0):

Just let your script call die($foobar).

You can let your script end with sth. like this:

> header('Content-Type: application/json');
>
> die(json_encode( $array ) )

to transport arrays in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You can create json web services instead of returning direct outptut

`echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success","message"=>"Your name is ".$_POST['firstname']." ".$_POST['lastname],"first_name"=>$_POST['firstname'],"last_name"=>$_POST['lastname']));`

change code in hr.onreadystatechange function

`var response = eval("(" + hr.responseText + ")");// convert response to json
if(response.status == "success"){

alert(response.message);//get you out put with variables first_name and last_name & message
}`

Answer (score 0):

How about returning your data as JSON.

```
$data = array(
    'firstname' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
    'lastname' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
die();
```

Then in javascript:

```
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
    alert("My name is " + jsonObj.firstname + " " + jsonObj.lastname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok we have many answers here, let me tell you a way that I think is the best to send the details like Username and Password to the server as AJAX request and the result is sent back.

Here are the simple fields of a HTML/php file lets say abc.php:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />

<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">

<div id="output"></div> //Shows the output or the success message 

<script>
 $("#submit").click(function() {
    var user = $("#username").val();           //Get the value from field username
    var pass = $("#password").val();            // same as above
    var obj = {'username': user, 'password': pass};               // create a plain object
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);              // convert to JSON string
    console.log(obj);  //Just for checking the output
    console.log(json); //same as above

    $.post('test.php', json ,function(response) {              //send to your service file "tst.php, the JSON
        alert(response);                     //see the response from the server

        if(!response) {                     //cases where data is not received
            $("#output").html("Server Not Responding, Please Try Again");
        }
        else {

            var data = JSON.parse(response);              //convert to JSON object
            $("#output").html(data.username);             //access the data received



        }
    });

});
 </script>
```

The test.php receives the json inside the html body and we can retrieve it, use it for checking the purposes like authentication and send messages or response code back. Here I have sent the same obj back

```
test.php
 <?php
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj = json_decode($json);
 echo json_encode($obj);

 ?>
```

Since the data sent and received is both json so writing "application/json" in AJax request  (abc.php) and mentioning the header("content-type: application/json") can be avoided.

Comment: Well you are now using jquery when it was first written in plain javascript.

Comment: Indeed jquery, you can write the same using Javascript but look how the php file tackles the data received from the post request sent from the first file..!!

Comment: i was not questioning if it was possible just that the original post is written in javascript.

Comment: "This is working fine but I would like to have a variable sent instead of echo is it possible?" 
I wrote the request just to show that data instead of echo can be sent and how to receive and use it. :)